# What is the oxygen carrying capacity of reticulocytes?

Tags: physiology, hematology, blood-circulation

What is the oxygen carrying capacity of immature red blood cells, or [reticulocytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reticulocyte)? Is there any difference between oxygen carrying capacity of mature and immature red blood cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was studied by Steve Fishbone et al and concluded that the Hb content of a Reticulocyte is slightly higher than that of a mature RBC. The CHr, which is the Hb content of a reticulocyte in CRF patients receiving Erythropoetin is around 27.5 +/- 2.5 pg

Ref: Fishbone S, et al. Reticulocyte Hemoglobin Content in the Evaluation of Iron Status of Hemodialysis Patients. Kid. Int., 1997; 52: 217-222

Comment: Interesting.  Is this the Hb content per cell?  Is it considered a normal value?

Comment: Hi Roland! Thats the value in CRF patients! It could be slightly lesser by about 5-10% in normal individuals